# How to disable an entire Blazor EditForm, along with all fields?

Tags: .net-core, blazor, .net-5

I'm used to the handy `form.disable()` method in Angular's reactive forms, which disables all bound fields in the given form group (which can be the whole form). And obviously enabling them in a similar fashion is also possible.

Is there a similar method hidden somewhere in the `EditForm` in .NET5 Blazor?

I haven't managed to find anything similar yet. In fact I haven't even found a way to iterate through all fields that are bound to the model.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could wrap your form inside a fieldset and bind the `disable`-property to a boolean-Property like so:

```
<form>
    <fieldset disabled="@IsDisabled">
        [... formfields ...]
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Oh, that's pretty cool. I've never encountered this HTML-based solution before, even though I presume it's been around for ages. This seems like a neat solution actually, so I'll accept it. But if it's okay, if a more Razor/Blazor-specific solution will turn out (basically on the level of a single method call) then I might change it to that (although I'm fairly confident that such a thing doesn't exist currently).